# Insert a line only one time in Makefile after the comments and empty lines

Tags: insert, replace, sed, grep

```
I have a scenario where in I need to change thousands of Makefiles. 
I need to insert a line in Makefile and it should be the first effect code 
(Ignore comments and empty lines if found in the beginning of the file).

In the below example, I need to insert a line NEWLINE=1 in the Makefile.

Source Makefile
---------------

# copy right info
(empty line here).
# The file is mainly for ....
(empty file again here)
# note


all:
    gcc sample.c

Target Makefile
---------------

# copy right info
(empty line here).
# The file is mainly for ....
(empty file again here)
# note

NEWLINE= 1

all:
    gcc sample.c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

touch ~/tmp
chmod 777 ~/tmp
echo sed -i \'$(grep -vnE "^$|^#" Makefile | head -1 | cut -f1 -d ":")iNEWLINE=1\' Makefile > ~/tmp
&& ~/tmp

Answer (score 0):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk '/all:/{print "NEWLINE =1\n\n" $0;next}1' source > tmp && mv tmp source
```

or

with `sed` (in-file substitution):

```
sed -i 's/all:/NEWLINE= 1\n\n&/' source
```